# Problem making an automatic cobblestone generator work

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to build an automatic cobblestone generator but my piston won't connect to my red stone.  The redstone line just stays a blotch and won't connect.  Help me!

Comment: A screenshot would really help in this instance.  If you can, try showing just the redstone components.

Comment: Upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com and paste the link into the question.

Comment: Actually, the post editing interface has an option to directly upload and embed an image. It uses imgur in the background, but it's simpler.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - As Connor is a new user, he doesn't have access to post images. (This is to prevent spam-bots posting images). http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: And now he can post images.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issues with a minecart dispenser. A couple of things that (I believe caused my piston to not activate, were:

- I couldn't have the redstone approach at an angle, and
- The redstone couldn't be above or below the piston.

So, make sure that your redstone is 'touching' a bottom edge of the piston (not a top, and not underneath), and the piece of restone touching the piston is connected in a straight line to another piece.

This,

```
--[]
|
```

Not this

```
-[]
|
```

(Top-down view)

Key:

```
- or | : Redstone wire
  []   : Piston
```